# Changing Pointer, after already changing default cursor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a stylized page, and have already changed the default cursor, but it goes back to the standard "pointer" when you mouse over a link. I want to change the standard pointer as I did with the default cursor. I tried some javascript that I found, but it didn't seem to work.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/basic.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<script>
    var elms = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    var n = elms.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
        if(window.getComputedStyle(elms[i]).cursor == "pointer") {
            elms[i].style.cursor = "url(../img/cursor.png)";
        }
     }
</script>

</head>
<body>
      <a>
      <a>
</body>  
</html>
```

and this was the CSS cursor

```
    html{
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height:100%;
    cursor: url(../img/cursor.png),auto;
}
body{
    background-color: black;
    cursor: url(../img/cursor.png),auto;
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the whole img link?

Comment: is this what you mean?     `file:///J:/Graphic/webfolio/img/cursor.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
a:hover, a:active, a:visited {
    cursor: url(../img/cursor.png), auto;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Kw3w/)

**P.S:** Used a random image in the demo.

Comment: I enjoy this fix because I'm trying to use as much CSS/HTML as i can, and minimize Js/Jquery. Thankyou!

Comment: It made me wait 5min for some reason, i dont know if its because someone down-voted me based on the fact that my html wasn't flushed, and didnt include my `</a>` ... ~rolls eyes~