# JavaFX WebView: how do I change the default cursor?

Tags: java, javafx, webview, caret

How do I change WebView's default cursor? Every change I make is ignored, the icon always reverts back to the default pointer.

Example:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX WebView Example");

        WebView webView = new WebView();
        webView.getEngine().loadContent("http://google.com");

        VBox vBox = new VBox(webView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 960, 600);

        scene.setCursor(Cursor.CLOSED_HAND); // Doesn't work, reverted to pointer
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I also tried to change the `webView` cursor itself, but to no avail.

Comment: Related: [JavaFX - Override WebView's Cursor Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40452987/javafx-override-webviews-cursor-change), but in that case it was sufficient to have the cursor change at the corners only. I need the change to hold for the whole WebView.

Comment: I'm only guessing, but did you try `webView.setCursor(Cursor.CLOSED_HAND);` ?

Comment: I did but to no result.

Comment: I found other tricks here: [JavaFX – How to change or hide mouse cursor in the entire application (WebView + Scene)](https://better-coding.com/javafx-how-to-change-or-hide-mouse-cursor-in-the-entire-application-webview-scene/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The document’s HTML content defines the cursor, so you can modify the document’s body style after it loads:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WebViewCursorOverride extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX WebView Example");

        WebView webView = new WebView();
        webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
            (o, old, state) -> {
                if (state != Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                    return;
                }

                Document doc = webView.getEngine().getDocument();
                Element body = (Element)
                    doc.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0);
                String style = body.getAttribute("style");
                body.setAttribute("style", "cursor: grab;" + style);
            });
        webView.getEngine().load("https://google.com");

        VBox vBox = new VBox(webView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 960, 600);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

You can also create your own cursor from an image:

```
body.setAttribute("style",
    "cursor: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8c/Pixel_51_icon_cursor_click_top_right.svg/36px-Pixel_51_icon_cursor_click_top_right.svg.png') 27 9, default;" + style);
```

The full definition of the `cursor` CSS property is [here](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-3/#propdef-cursor).  Here is the current list of predefined cursors;  note that not all of them are supported on every system:

- auto
- default
- none
- context-menu
- help
- pointer
- progress
- wait
- cell
- crosshair
- text
- vertical-text
- alias
- copy
- move
- no-drop
- not-allowed
- grab
- grabbing
- e-resize
- n-resize
- ne-resize
- nw-resize
- s-resize
- se-resize
- sw-resize
- w-resize
- ew-resize
- ns-resize
- nesw-resize
- nwse-resize
- col-resize
- row-resize
- all-scroll
- zoom-in
- zoom-out

Comment: Nice! I think an alternative is to use `webView.getEngine().executeScript("document.body.style.cursor = 'grab';");`

Comment: `Element` doesn't have the method `getAttribute` in JavaFX 10.

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct Element class, namely [org.w3c.dom.Element](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html).  (It’s in the same package as Document.)

Comment: Thank you! The cursor is changed completely! To keep the hand for hyperlinks, I can use this:
[Changing Pointer, after already changing default cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623562/changing-pointer-after-already-changing-default-cursor)

Comment: I tried a more fancy custom cursor and unfortunately, your solution shows the default cursor flickering while moving the mouse. It seems WebView tries to revert back to the default choice after every mouse action.

Answer (score 2):

The solution by @VGR is elegant, but induces flickering on my machine.

A more drastic solution is replacing the `CursorManager` used by `WebEngine` by something else.

For example, in Java10 you can create this `CursorManagerImpl2` class based on the default `CursorManagerImpl`:

```java
import com.sun.webkit.CursorManager;
import com.sun.webkit.graphics.WCGraphicsManager;
import com.sun.webkit.graphics.WCImage;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.ImageCursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.*;

public class CursorManagerImpl2 extends CursorManager<javafx.scene.Cursor> {
    private final Map<String, javafx.scene.Cursor> map = new HashMap();
    private ResourceBundle bundle;
    private javafx.scene.Cursor defaultCursor = javafx.scene.Cursor.DEFAULT;

    public CursorManagerImpl2() {}

    public CursorManagerImpl2(javafx.scene.Cursor defaultCursor) {
      this.defaultCursor = defaultCursor;
    }

    public javafx.scene.Cursor getDefaultCursor() {
      return defaultCursor;
    }

    public void setDefaultCursor(javafx.scene.Cursor cursor) {
      defaultCursor = cursor;
    }

    @Override
    protected javafx.scene.Cursor getCustomCursor(WCImage image, int hotspotX, int hotspotY) {
      return new ImageCursor(
          com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getImageAccessor()
              .fromPlatformImage(WCGraphicsManager.getGraphicsManager().toPlatformImage(image)),
          hotspotX,
          hotspotY);
    }
    @Override
    protected javafx.scene.Cursor getPredefinedCursor(int type) {
      switch (type) {
        case 0:
        default: return defaultCursor; // line changed
        case 1: return javafx.scene.Cursor.CROSSHAIR;
        case 2: return javafx.scene.Cursor.HAND;
        case 3: return javafx.scene.Cursor.MOVE;
        case 4: return javafx.scene.Cursor.TEXT;
        case 5: return javafx.scene.Cursor.WAIT;
        case 6: return this.getCustomCursor("help", javafx.scene.Cursor.DEFAULT);
        case 7: return javafx.scene.Cursor.E_RESIZE;
        case 8: return javafx.scene.Cursor.N_RESIZE;
        case 9: return javafx.scene.Cursor.NE_RESIZE;
        case 10: return javafx.scene.Cursor.NW_RESIZE;
        case 11: return javafx.scene.Cursor.S_RESIZE;
        case 12: return javafx.scene.Cursor.SE_RESIZE;
        case 13: return javafx.scene.Cursor.SW_RESIZE;
        case 14: return javafx.scene.Cursor.W_RESIZE;
        case 15: return javafx.scene.Cursor.V_RESIZE;
        case 16: return javafx.scene.Cursor.H_RESIZE;
        case 17: return this.getCustomCursor("resize.nesw", javafx.scene.Cursor.DEFAULT);
        case 18: return this.getCustomCursor("resize.nwse", javafx.scene.Cursor.DEFAULT);
        case 19: return this.getCustomCursor("resize.column", javafx.scene.Cursor.H_RESIZE);
        case 20: return this.getCustomCursor("resize.row", javafx.scene.Cursor.V_RESIZE);
        case 21: return this.getCustomCursor("panning.middle", javafx.scene.Cursor.DEFAULT);
        case 22: return this.getCustomCursor("panning.east", javafx.scene.Cursor.DEFAULT);
        case 23: return this.getCustomCursor("panning.north", javafx.scene.Cursor.DEFAULT);
        case 24: return this.getCustomCursor("panning.ne", javafx.scene.Cursor.DEFAULT);
        case 25: return this.getCustomCursor("panning.nw", javafx.scene.Cursor.DEFAULT);
        case 26: return this.getCustomCursor("panning.south", javafx.scene.Cursor.DEFAULT);
        case 27: return this.getCustomCursor("panning.se", javafx.scene.Cursor.DEFAULT);
        case 28: return this.getCustomCursor("panning.sw", javafx.scene.Cursor.DEFAULT);
        case 29: return this.getCustomCursor("panning.west", javafx.scene.Cursor.DEFAULT);
        case 30: return this.getCustomCursor("vertical.text", javafx.scene.Cursor.DEFAULT);
        case 31: return this.getCustomCursor("cell", javafx.scene.Cursor.DEFAULT);
        case 32: return this.getCustomCursor("context.menu", javafx.scene.Cursor.DEFAULT);
        case 33: return this.getCustomCursor("no.drop", javafx.scene.Cursor.DEFAULT);
        case 34: return this.getCustomCursor("not.allowed", javafx.scene.Cursor.DEFAULT);
        case 35: return this.getCustomCursor("progress", javafx.scene.Cursor.WAIT);
        case 36: return this.getCustomCursor("alias", javafx.scene.Cursor.DEFAULT);
        case 37: return this.getCustomCursor("zoom.in", javafx.scene.Cursor.DEFAULT);
        case 38: return this.getCustomCursor("zoom.out", javafx.scene.Cursor.DEFAULT);
        case 39: return this.getCustomCursor("copy", javafx.scene.Cursor.DEFAULT);
        case 40: return javafx.scene.Cursor.NONE;
        case 41: return this.getCustomCursor("grab", javafx.scene.Cursor.OPEN_HAND);
        case 42: return this.getCustomCursor("grabbing", javafx.scene.Cursor.CLOSED_HAND);
      }
    }

    private javafx.scene.Cursor getCustomCursor(String cursorId, javafx.scene.Cursor defaultCursor) {
      javafx.scene.Cursor customCursor = this.map.get(cursorId);
      if (customCursor == null) {
        try {
          if (this.bundle == null) {
            this.bundle =
                ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.sun.javafx.webkit.Cursors", Locale.getDefault());
          }

          if (this.bundle != null) {
            String fileName = this.bundle.getString(cursorId + ".file");
            javafx.scene.image.Image image =
                new Image(com.sun.javafx.webkit.CursorManagerImpl.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName));
            fileName = this.bundle.getString(cursorId + ".hotspotX");
            int hotspotX = Integer.parseInt(fileName);
            fileName = this.bundle.getString(cursorId + ".hotspotY");
            int hotspotY = Integer.parseInt(fileName);
            customCursor = new ImageCursor(image, hotspotX, hotspotY);
          }
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
        }

        if (customCursor == null) {
          customCursor = defaultCursor;
        }

        this.map.put(cursorId, customCursor);
      }

      return customCursor;
    }
}
```

You can then replace the manager with

```java
CursorManager.setCursorManager(new CursorManagerImpl2(javafx.scene.Cursor.CROSSHAIR));
```

To change the default cursor, you can use

```java
((CursorManagerImpl2) CursorManager.getCursorManager()).setDefaultCursor(javafx.scene.Cursor.MOVE);
```

Note that you might have to add the `com.sun` packages to your gradle:

```
compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs.addAll(['--add-exports=javafx.web/com.sun.webkit=ALL-UNNAMED', '--add-exports=javafx.web/com.sun.javafx.webkit=ALL-UNNAMED', '--add-exports=javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED', '--add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk=ALL-UNNAMED'])
}
run {
    jvmArgs = ['--add-exports=javafx.web/com.sun.webkit=ALL-UNNAMED', '--add-exports=javafx.web/com.sun.javafx.webkit=ALL-UNNAMED', '--add-exports=javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED', '--add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk=ALL-UNNAMED']
}
```

With this, I do not suffer from any flickering while moving the mouse, even when using large custom cursors.

The big downside (beside the com.sun imports) is that the `CursorManager` is static; as such, all `WebViews` will use the same cursor management.